# Is Quickening a gypsy morph?

Tags: shannara, terry-brooks

In **The Druid Of Shannara** (book 2 of the Heritage series), we meet *Quickening*, who is created by The King Of The Silver River from the elements. In the **Word and the Void** and **Genesis** series we meet a similar creature defined as a *gypsy morph*, and it is revealed that he is also created by The King Of The Silver River in a similar way.

The question is: is Quickening also a  gypsy morph, or is she a different type of magical creature with similar properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Quickening is not a gypsy morph, although they are very similar in nature, in that they are created creatures usually meant for a specific task.

However, in the Shannara Wikia, it notes that Quickening is an Elemental.

> Elemental is a term for a being created out of the elements, most often by Faerie creatures. An Elemental can be made to appear human or take on other forms, and is usually created for a specific task.

The same site defines a gypsy morph as follows:

> A gypsy morph is a Faerie creature created by wild magic.

As the definitions show, one is deliberate, the other comes out of wild magic.

In *[Angel Fire East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Fire_East)*, we are introduced to the gypsy morph, and this explanation is given for its creation (Emphasis mine)

> A gypsy morph was rare and dangerous. **Formed of loose, wild magics come together in the ether**. a morph had the potential of becoming a weapon of incredible power.

So while they are similar creatures of Faerie magic, Quickening was created specifically and is not a gypsy morph.